# How to get keyboard to work with newest Ubuntu in VMware Player

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player

I just upgraded to the newest version of Ubuntu, which I run in VMware Player.  After reboot I can't enter my password.  The keyboard doesn't seem to work with it even though it works fine outside of VMware.

Comment: You need to recompile the kernel.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown the Ubuntu Session and in the vmware player, click on your Ubuntu image then click edit Virtual Machine Settings. Click the options tab, Make sure General is highlighted in the left pane, then check the box that reads use enhanced virtual keyboard in the lower left corner. Should fix your problem.